# Elements of a Structure Not Saving

Tags: c

I've been trying to do a leaderboard program for school, but I've noticed that the program overwrites the first player when trying to add new ones.
Am I doing something wrong?
The code accepts the players just fine, but opposed to adding new players to the leader board it just overwrites the first one completely.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int number,i,key,newscore,a;
struct playerdata
{
  char fname[50],lname[50];
  int id,score;
}playerstats[5];


void welcome()
{

    printf("\nWelcome to the leaderboard, challenger!");
    printf("\nPlease select an option:");
    printf("\n1-Add 5 players at a time\n2-Display all stats\n3-Update score\n4-Show player ranking\n5-Add 1 player");
    printf("\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    switch(number)
    {
        case 1:
        fillplayer();
        break;

        case 2:
        displaystats();
        break;

        case 3:
        updatescore();
        break;

        case 4:
        playerranking();
        break;

        case 5:
        addplayer();
        break;

        default:
        printf("\nThis option is invalid");
    }
}

void fillplayer()                                    //read player info//
{

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter your first name.");
        scanf("%s", &playerstats[i].fname);
        printf("\nPlease enter your last name.");
        scanf("%s", &playerstats[i].lname);
        printf("Please enter your player ID (Any random 4 digit number)");
        scanf("%d",&playerstats[i].id);
        printf("\n Please enter your score");
        scanf("%d",&playerstats[i].score);
    }

}

void displaystats()                              //Output player info//
{
    printf("\nFirstName\tLast Name\tID\tScore\t");
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s\t\t%s\t\t%d\t\t%d",playerstats[i].fname,playerstats[i].lname,playerstats[i].id,playerstats[i].score);
    }  
}

void addplayer()                                    //read one player's info//
{

        printf("\nPlease enter your first name.");
        scanf("%s", &playerstats[i].fname);
        printf("\nPlease enter your last name.");
        scanf("%s", &playerstats[i].lname);
        printf("Please enter your player ID (Any random 4 digit number)");
        scanf("%d",&playerstats[i].id);
        printf("\n Please enter your score");
        scanf("%d",&playerstats[i].score);


}

int searchplayer(void)
{
   printf("\nEnter your player ID");
   scanf("%d", &key);
   {
       if (playerstats[i].id=key)
       {
           return a;
       }
       else
       {
           return  -1;
       }
   }
}   


void updatescore()
{
    a=searchplayer();
    if (playerstats[i].id==key)
    {
       printf ("\nYour ID is%d", playerstats[i].id);
       printf("\nEnter your new high score");
       scanf("%d",&newscore);
       if (newscore>playerstats[i].score)
       {
           playerstats[i].score=newscore;
           printf("Score successfully changed to %d", newscore);
       }
       else
       {
            printf("\nThis score is less than your current highscore, the high score shall not be changed");
       }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nInvalid ID");
    }
}

void playerranking()
{
    printf("\n not done");
}

int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<999;i++)
    {
      welcome();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit to make your [mre] more minimal. Deleting empty lines might go a long way in that direction...

Comment: Where do you initialise the global `i`  used inside the functions?

Comment: right under the first line

Comment: It is only defined there, not explicitly initialised. The value it gets implicitly there is never changing. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a local loop counter `i` inside the function `main()` and some other function.
You have a (not explicitly initialised) global variable `i` which is used inside other functions.
They are not the same.
You never change the global `i`, which is e.g. used in the relevant function `addplayer()`.

To solve I recommend to:

- define to yourself the meaning and use of the global variable
- name it accordingly
- introduce some way of changing it, maybe more options in the menu
- use it as parameter to called functions
- also use it in the function which adds 5 players at once (or that will always overwrite the same first five), i.e. use the sum of global "current" and local loop counter
- quite hard, but probably what you want: use the global via pointer parameter in functions which are supposed to change it; e.g. especially the add5 function
- consider all the globals; generally try to avoid globals, they got you into the trouble you are currently experiencing

Comment: So should i not use global variables for the loops at  all? What should i add or take away so that the new inputs wont overwrite the old ones? I'm really sorry i'm still really new to programming..

Comment: You have not used a global for any of your loops. Both start with `for(int i=`, i.e. they are using locals.

Comment: You would have to add something which changes the global. See the third recommendation in the list. Try a `i++;` inside `addplayer()` to get an idea of what I mean. But understand that it is not the solutoin. You most lilkely will want a way to select any value.

Comment: Rekader, please let me know how I can make my answer more helpful to you.